# Error while configuring libpng: "zlib not installed"

Tags: c, mingw, zlib, libpng, msys

OS: Win7, using MinGW, sh.exe from MSYS

```
./configure --prefix=/mingw
```

with and without prefix ends like this:

```
checking for zlibVersion in -lz... no
checking for yeszlibVersion in -lz... no
configure: error: zlib not installed
```

i've installed zlib through cmake, it went smoothly and without errors, so i have all zlib files in my bin, lib and include folders
what can be the problem? how do i fix this?

**UPD**
looks like it's because i have libzlib.dll and not libz.dll in bin folder, but that's how it installed and i still don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently faced this issue, And this is fixed so I can answer this question.

If you are building cross compiler
Define host and path to library using `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

example:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I$PREFIX/include" LDFLAGS="-L$PREFIX/lib" ./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --host=$TARGET
```

If you are not building cross compiler. Then either specify the path (to library and header files) or install zlib devel package.